# JSNI return after timeout

Tags: java, gwt, return, timeout, response

I am using GWT and I have one native function called from Java class which have some code it will take couple of seconds to produced the result and return it back to java code. But unfortunately it return blank because of native function return early before its inside service response back.

Here is the code

This function called from Java class.

```
public static native String getChartPng(int indexing)/*-{
        var result;
        //getPngBase64String(onSuccess, onError, width, height, img quality)
        if($wnd.chartings[indexing]){
            $wnd.chartings[indexing].getPngBase64String(function(response){
                //it takes couple of seconds
                result = response;

            },null,450,600,1);
        }
        return result
    }-*/;
```

So when I called this function I got the blank String. How I got the result back from using this code ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're using `AnyChart`. Here is the [getPngBase64String reference](https://api.anychart.com/7.12.0/anychart.core.Chart#getPngBase64String).

This method is asynchronous, which means that code execution is continued without waiting for the method to complete. That's why the next statement: `return result` is called immediately, with unassigned `result`.

The `getPngBase64String` method in first two parameters takes callback functions that are called when the method execution ends with success (first callback) or failure (second callback). You can only use the result in the `onSuccess` callback.

So you need to think about asynchronous methods like this: go and do something for me and let me know when you're done. The method will let you know by calling a callback function on success (or failure).

So you can not just return the result. Instead you should do something with the result in a callback function.

Comment: Yes, I am using anychart, I know this solution, do whatever inside success callback function, but I want to return that value...

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to return the result you would need to cheat a little bit. But first I need to say that this is **the wrong way** and you really should think about revising your approach.

You can use some flag to wait for the result. Like this:

```
public static native String getChartPng(int indexing) /*-{
    var result_ready = false;
    var result;
    //getPngBase64String(onSuccess, onError, width, height, img quality)
    if($wnd.chartings[indexing]){
        $wnd.chartings[indexing].getPngBase64String(function(response){
            //it takes couple of seconds
            result = response;
            result_ready = true;
        }, null, 450, 600, 1);
    }

    while(!result_ready);  // do nothing, wait for the result - notice the `;`

    return result
}-*/;
```

This is called [busy waiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting) and you should avoid that.